# Using Groovy, how can I read a file as ASCII?

Tags: unicode, groovy, ascii

I need to read a text file and then pass it along to another method as ASCII. I'm new to Groovy and this one has me twitterpated.

If I do:

```
String pubKey = new File(textFileLocation).text
```

The result is not ASCII characters as the target method chucks out an Exception to that effect. If I cut and paste the value in as a String literal instead of reading it from a file, it works fine.

Note that Linux says it is an ASCII file:

```
123@456 529 squirb $ file ~/sometext.txt 
/home/123/456/sometext.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Comment: Have you tried getting text with ASCII charset as `new File(textFileLocation).getText('US-ASCII')`?

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace. What is the size of the file? Why does Linux say it has "very long lines" ?

Comment: Once you have it in a string, it is not ASCII anymore, it is Unicode, as all string in JVM are Unicode (UTF-16). You should either use getText with charset (as dmahapatro recommended), or keep it as a bunch of bytes (with getBytes).

Comment: In response to Michael Easter, I'm using Jasypt in gmaven to encrypt /decrypt properties using randomly generated key as the pw for pw encryption. It's sufficient for our needs without being too onerous for developers, i.e. they won't have to enter creds every single time they build. Encryption in the first place is overkill for resources used strictly for testing but we do have a requirement to satisfy. :-/

Comment: Well I know how to fix this now but not exactly why.  If you follow up the first line with:
pubKey = new String (pubKey); the exception goes away and everything is hunky dory. Weird.